# Can't seem to set up tesseract module with Pycharmpy

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have been trying to set up tesseract for a couple hours now with no luck. I have checked cmd and made sure that tesseract itself is working, but no matter what i do I can't get the python module to work. My shool has me using python 3.6 on pycharm. If anybody has experience or could help my set up this module it would be greatly appreciated, tyvm and have a good day

Comment: Can you add some more details about what you've tried, error messages you're receiving, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i was making it so much more complicate than it had to be. Do this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

for both pillow and pytesseract